# Merge 'clockworkmod-recovery' into 'clockworkmod'

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I just saw we've got another dupe here: [clockworkmod-recovery](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clockworkmod-recovery) (× 9) and [clockworkmod](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clockworkmod) (× 236). I don't think we need them both. The latter has a decent tag-wiki already, and is the more frequently used one. Hence I suggest to merge the former into the latter. Not sure we need to make it a synonym, but that might prevent it from being re-created – so I've already marked it accordingly.

Comment: `clockworkmod-recovery` actually seems like the better master tag to me. It's more specific, and "ClockworkMod" could also refer to the entity (Koush) that creates various apps (search for apps made by ClockworkMod [on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=ClockworkMod), for example).

Comment: I would tend to agree. I can't see a reason why we should have questions about "ClockworkMod" the entity, so it makes sense to me that `clockworkmod-recovery` is the master tag, with `clockworkmod` as a synonym.

Comment: That would then mean to also rename the 'twrp' tag. I don't know what that would mean to all the places referring there via `[tag:clockworkmod]` and `[tag:twrp]` (guess I'm not the only one using these macros in answers and tag wikis). So if you decide to go that way, please ensure that the original tags at least remain as synonyms.

Comment: I don't really see the corollary there, to be honest. "TeamWin" is the entity, and "TeamWin Recovery Project" (TWRP) is the recovery. That's basically the same situation that I was trying to point out here. If we had a `teamwin` tag then I would say it should be merged with `twrp` (or `teamwin-recovery` or something), but we don't, because nobody is asking questions about the *entity*, TeamWin.

Comment: And synonymizing them should handle any inbound links, AFAIK. They'll just redirect to the master's page. I'd make sure the tag wiki was brought over to the new master tag.

Comment: OK, in this case I'm fine with both approaches ;) I just prefer "short tags" over "long names" (no, I better don't ask for a `cwm` synonym #D) – but that's covered as well as long as both stay, no matter which one becomes the synonym :)

Comment: Just FYI: the tag merge tool appears to be broken at the moment. When the SE team gets that sorted out I'll do the merge.

Comment: @eldarerathis Just a ping (as a non-mod I cannot check): Is the merge tool working again, so this task could be completed? As our mods rarely appear in chat, I unfortunately cannot ask there :(

Comment: Still not working. I created a bug report on this Meta site: [Attempting to merge tags results in an error page](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1809)

Comment: @eldarerathis thanks! Upvoted it to give it some more weight. Good idea to link it here; when checking back next time, before "sending out pings" I can simply check there whether the problem still exists first.

Comment: @eldarerathis Looks like you can mark this one "completed"? :) Thanks a lot for your efforts!