# Attempting to merge tags results in an error page

Tags: bug, tags, tag-synonyms

I've been periodically attempting to merge two tags over the past ~3 weeks - as per the discussion in [this Meta question](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1805/merge-clockworkmod-recovery-into-clockworkmod) - but have been unable to do so. The first few steps of the merge process work alright: I can select the two tags, and the merge preview gets pulled up correctly, but when I hit the button to actually perform the merge, I get kicked out to the [Something Bad Happened<sup>TM</sup>](https://android.stackexchange.com/error) page.

If relevant, the specific tags I'm attempting to merge are [clockworkmod](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clockworkmod) and [clockworkmod-recovery](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clockworkmod-recovery), with the former being set as a synonym of the latter.

Additional information that appears to possibly be relevant: there was a synonym suggestion awaiting approval that was going to map [clockworkmod-recovery](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clockworkmod-recovery) to [clockworkmod](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clockworkmod). This is the **opposite** of the merge we were trying to perform, so I'm suspecting that it was causing the system to bomb out because it couldn't reconcile the attempted merge with the synonym suggestion. I was able to complete the merge by doing the following:

1. Went into the synonym suggestions and clicked "swap" to reverse the direction of the [clockworkmod-recovery](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clockworkmod-recovery)→[clockworkmod](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clockworkmod) synonym suggestion
2. Approved the swapped synonym
3. Performed a merge

Comment: I saw the same behavior just now, with an without the synonym.  Then I tried the reverse without synonym -- which succeeded.  Then I tried renaming it (via merge), which also failed.  Interestingly, `clockworkmod-recovery (s)` showed in the auto-complete, despite the fact that it should not exist any more and is not a synonym either.  (It is suggested as a synonym for `clockworkmod`, however; that suggestion ought to have been removed along with the tag, I would think.)

Comment: That suggestion was mine. Maybe a couple more votes for it would "push it through" automatically?

Comment: @Izzy I think that synonym suggestion may have been relevant here. I was able to complete the merge by going into the synonym suggestion and reversing it to point the other direction, approving it, and then doing the merge.

Comment: Good point! And glad it solved that way. Still I'd consider this a bug, as the system should have either resolved it automatically or at least pointed out the "conflict".